# How to quickly understand a huge piece of code

Tags: source-code, maintenance

(This is a general question but I think is important.)

How do you quickly understand a huge piece of code, say, a project with tens of thousands of lines of code (written by other people)?

Are there any useful source analysis tools (for example, call graph visualizer) or IDEs that may be helpful? Any techniques are also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: @McMannus saying it's a duplicate and then referencing to a question marked as duplicate?

Comment: @PieterB don't wanted to go down the long duplicate chain =)

Comment: Tools do exist - what language are you using?

Comment: @RobbieDee Mainly C++ and Java. Mixed with C.

Comment: Never used it myself, but I believe CodeSonar covers all those: http://www.grammatech.com/codesonar/source-code